# Does Ubuntu 64 bit boot and work on an iMac 32 bit?

Tags: boot

Does Ubuntu 64 bit boot and work on an iMac 32 bit, or the 32 bit version is the only one possible to work?

Answer (score 3):

32-bit chipsets can only run 32-bit operating systems. If your iMac is 32-bit, you'll have to get the 32-bit version of Ubuntu.

If this Mac is a PowerPC Mac, you're going to have to install a special version of Ubuntu. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads

If it's an Intel Mac, install the normal 32-bit version of Ubuntu.

Provide the model of your iMac and I can provide more specifics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. My old iMac is a desktop all-in-one, model 4,1. 2GHz processor Intel Core Duo with 2 GB of Ram Memory, Bus connection is 667 MHz.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to use a 32-bit version of Ubuntu if you want to install it. Your Mac is Intel, so you should be able to just get the normal 32-bit version of Ubuntu.